# How to validate Twitter consumer key & secret

Tags: twitter

I have a pair of keys: consumer key & consumer key secret. I want to validate it. How to do?

Just like Facebook validate appID using http://graph.facebook.com/< appID >

Comment: API version 1.1 have any validation url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

This page in Twitter dev centre should hopefully explain all, i am not sure what you mean by Validate (as in whether you mean test or implement) but either way this will help :)